# Not able to login into Ubuntu 16.04 LTS even if the password is correct

Tags: login

I'm not able to login even if the password is correct . Whenever I try to login it accepts the password but returns back to the login screen . Please help

Comment: Switch to a terminal (ctrl+alt+f4) and try logging in.  If you can login normally, you could be out of space (the GUI needs space to create work files that are deleted on logout).  Enter `df -hl` and check especially for space in your $HOME (/home/user) directory/partition. If it's full (0 or near 0 bytes free) you need to delete some files, then you can switch back to GUI and you'll find the gui will work.  When the gui can't create the needed [temporary] files on login, the gui just returns you to the login screen as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to a terminal (ctrl+alt+f4) and try logging in. If you can login normally, you could be out of space (the GUI needs [temporary work] space to create [work] files that are deleted on logout).

Enter `df -hl`  (disk free, human output, local drives only) and check especially for space in your $HOME (/home/user) directory/partition.

If it's full (0 or near 0 bytes free) you need to delete some files, then you can switch back to GUI and you'll find the gui will work. When the gui can't create the needed [temporary] files on login, the gui just returns you to the login screen as you describe without any message.

(there are other alternatives; but less likely in my experience.  `df -hi` to check you inodes free, to gui permissions... but I'd try disk space first..)

Answer (score 0):

At login, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to text console, and login there.
Try following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

and if its not help, then:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and try to login.